# how to pass a value from model to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have model like this

```
public class Server implements Serializable {

    private String serverIp;

    public String getServerIp() {
        return serverIp;
    }

    public void setServerIp(String serverIp) {
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
    }

}
```

I need to get this ServerIp in a jsp file. How to do this?

Comment: have you even searched for [that](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-ip-address-in-java/) in the Internet?

Comment: I did and I tried this <input type="hidden" id="serverIp" value="${Server.serverIp}"/> But getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller part

```
@ModelAtribute("server")
public Server createServer(){
    Server server = new Server();
    //Set value of your server
    return server;
}
```

and in jsp

${server.serverIp}